# JavaScript Refreshes in Production - IIS

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iis, bundling-and-minification

I've looked around and tried to understand this but I don't get it.

Why when I issue a new release to Production with an update to a javascript file, does the User's browser not get the latest version.

Surely, if the javascript file has a new date due to it being changed, then the browser's version should be older and it should therefore request the newer version.

Instead, users have to press CTRL Shift R to do a force refresh.

What am I missing?  Is there a setting I need to change in IIS?

We use Google Chrome as the browser.  Javascript and CSS files are minified and bundled.

Comment: Chrome cached javascript,img and css((. if you want your users to receive a new js, you must rename js file, maybe add version, as example: "<js-name>-1.4".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser is meant to cache js (and css) files, to optimise page load times. It won't check the modified datetime on the file.

The easiest way to prevent this is to add a query string to the js file path, then amend it each time you change the file. This will force the browser to reload the file. E.g.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="script.js?v=1"></script>
```

If it's not a flat html file, it generally makes sense to code the query string server-side.

Comment: Thanks. If the script is used from many files, is there a good way to manage changing the version number in the path?  I assume the actual filename doesn't change.

Comment: That depends on the platform/technology you're using really. Any decent CMS would allow for shared header components, so you could manage the version number across the site by just amending that one shared component. If you're using flat html pages, but have common files between them, you'd probably want to use a server side include: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

Answer (score 0):

Chrome cached javascript,img and css((. if you want your users to receive a new js, you must rename js file, maybe add version